# Error loading class org.apache.solr.handler.component.CollapseComponent while starting solr

Tags: solr

using Tomcat 6.0

I have configured CollapseComponent in solrconfig.xml but am getting a error loading class:

```
<searchComponent name="collapse" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.CollapseComponent" />
```

Solr version 3.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solr field collapsing](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-236) was released as a part of stable release 3.3 and does not require special configuration.
As well, it does not require any special components to be included. So you can remove it.
Passing group=true&group.field=some_field should have it working without any changes.